# Java: Erro ao recuperar dados de ResultSet, mesmo a query estando correta

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, h2database

Meu problema é o seguinte:

Estou fazendo uma aplicação Java integrada com o banco de dados H2.

Eu faço uma query via `PreparedStatement` e salvo em um `ResultSet`. Até aí tudo certo, nenhuma exception é gerada.

No método seguinte, eu uso os métodos get... do `ResultSet` para pegar 
cada um dos valores das colunas retornados.

Mas acontece a seguinte exception:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: No data is available [2000-197]

Ok, está dizendo que o `ResultSet` está vazio. Mas a query está correta e deveria retornar um valor. Como vocês podem ver no print abaixo que fiz da tela do H2, fazendo a mesma query:

[image: Print de tela do H2 Engine]

E esse é o método onde eu tento extrair os valores resultantes da query:

```
private ContaCorrente montarConta(ResultSet resultSet) {

 System.out.println("ResultSet no montar conta: " + resultSet);

 ContaCorrente conta = new ContaCorrente();
 Class estaClasse = getClass();

 try {
  conta.setAgencia(resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_AGENCIA), estaClasse);
  conta.setNumero(resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_NUMCONTA), estaClasse);
  conta.setCliente(resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_CLIENTE), estaClasse);
  conta.setChqEspecial(resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_CHQESPECIAL));
  conta.setPacote(resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_PACOTE));
  conta.setSaldo(resultSet.getDouble(COLUNA_SALDO), estaClasse);
  conta.setSenha(resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_SENHA), estaClasse);
  conta.setDtAbertura(resultSet.getDate(COLUNA_DTABERTURA), estaClasse);

 } catch (SQLException e) {
  System.err.println("Falha no banco de dados ao recuperar conta corrente");
  System.err.println(e);
 } catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println("Falha geral ao recuperar conta corrente");
 }

 return conta;
}
```

O código de teste da query na main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 int agencia = 4512;
 int conta = 6918;

 ContaControler control = new ContaControler();
 ContaCorrente conta1 = new ContaCorrente();
 conta1 = control.getContaCorrente(4512, 6918);

 System.out.println(conta1.getAgencia());
 System.out.println(conta1.getNumConta());
}
```

E esse é o print de resultado:

> ```
> ResultSet no montar conta: rs0: org.h2.result.LocalResult@d041cf columns: 8 rows: 1 pos: -1
>
> 0   //ISSO AQUI É O PRINT DO NÚMERO DE AGÊNCIA NO MAIN
>
> 0   // E ESSE É O DA CONTA
>
> //ABAIXO: O RESULTADO DO "CATCH" DO TRY-CATCH
>
> Falha no banco de dados ao recuperar conta corrente
>
> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: No data is available [2000-197]
> ```

Já olhei o `Javadoc` do `Resultset` e tentei algumas coisas, mas não descobri até agora qual pode ser o problema. Palpites?

Comment: Você moveu o cursor pra primeira linha antes de chamar o método `montarConta` ?

Comment: Não.  Por padrão deveira vir na primeira não? Se bem que vendo o print out do objeto Resultset, diz POS -1... Deve ser isso então. Vou ver.

Comment: Mas isso não muda nada. Uma vez que, ao fazer um getInt() no resultSet eu passo o índice da coluna que eu quero: 1, 2, 3... e retorna vazio. Eu já tentei resitrar o valor só de uma coluna e dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: Ao mover o cursor para a posição zero, a exception que dá é "NullPointer Exception". Mas continua não retornando dados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você pode conferir [na documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) de obtenção de valores de `ResultSet` você deve chamar o método [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) antes de realizar a obtenção dos dados:

```
while(resultSet.next()){
    conta.setAgencia( resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_AGENCIA), estaClasse);
    conta.setNumero( resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_NUMCONTA), estaClasse);
    conta.setCliente( resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_CLIENTE), estaClasse);
    conta.setChqEspecial( resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_CHQESPECIAL));
    conta.setPacote( resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_PACOTE));
    conta.setSaldo( resultSet.getDouble(COLUNA_SALDO), estaClasse);
    conta.setSenha( resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_SENHA), estaClasse);
    conta.setDtAbertura( resultSet.getDate(COLUNA_DTABERTURA), estaClasse);
}
```

Ou

```
resultSet.next()
conta.setAgencia( resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_AGENCIA), estaClasse);
conta.setNumero( resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_NUMCONTA), estaClasse);
conta.setCliente( resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_CLIENTE), estaClasse);
conta.setChqEspecial( resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_CHQESPECIAL));
conta.setPacote( resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_PACOTE));
conta.setSaldo( resultSet.getDouble(COLUNA_SALDO), estaClasse);
conta.setSenha( resultSet.getInt(COLUNA_SENHA), estaClasse);
conta.setDtAbertura( resultSet.getDate(COLUNA_DTABERTURA), estaClasse);
```

---

> [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next())
>
> Moves the `cursor` froward one row from its current position. A `ResultSet` `cursor` is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method `next` makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.

Ou em tradução livre:

> Move o `cursor` em frente uma linha da posição atual. Um `cursor` de `ResultSet` está inicialmente posicionado antes da primeira linha; a primeira chamada para o método `next` faz a primeira linha ser a atual; a segunda chamada faz a segunda linha ser a atual, e assim por diante.